# I can load a dynamic page from within my site but when I click a link on the page and then try to return to that same page it wont load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js, router

I am trying to make a portfolio site using Next JS & React.

I have a [projectid] page that loads a component called "project page" which then checks the "router.query" and looks in a data array for an object with an id that matches it. Once the matching id is found it builds the page using the data within the object.

Now, this works perfectly when I click any of the project page links from within my site. I get brought to the correct project and the data is taken from my array and displayed properly.

However, these project pages have links on them to github. The problem occurs when I click the link and then go to github and then click the "back button" on my browser. Instead of loading the project page I get this message -

**"Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'currentProject' as it is undefined."**

I want it to just load the page as normal like it is when I access it from my site directly.

I guess that before my page can get the data from the object array it is already trying to load the component and then throwing the error.

I am not very experienced in Next JS and tried my best to resolve this. Any help would be appreicated.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import classes from "/pages/projects/ProjectInfo.module.css";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import projectData from "/components/projects/projectData";
import Navigation from "/components/sections/Navigation";

export default function ProjectPage() {
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(`this is the router ${router.query.projectId}`);

  const currentProject = projectData.find((project) => project.id === router.query.projectId);

  const {
    id,
    title,
    content,
    image,
    imageTwo,
    imageThree,
    imageFour,
    description,
    objective,
    tech,
    process,
    development,
    weblink,
    github,
  } = currentProject;

  // console.log(id, title, content, image);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation />
      <div className={classes.project_container}>
        <div className={classes.image_container}>
          <div className={classes.image}>
            <Image
              className={classes.image_style}
              src={imageTwo}
              alt={title}
              objectFit="cover"
              objectPosition="top center"
              // layout="fill"
              // layout="intrinsic"
            />
          </div>
          <div className={classes.image}>
            <Image
              className={classes.image_style}
              src={imageThree}
              alt={title}
              objectFit="cover"
              objectPosition="top center"
              // layout="fill"
              // layout="intrinsic"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.project_title}>
          <h1>{router.query.projectId}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.project_description}>
          <p>{description}</p>
        </div>

        <div className={classes.sidebar}>
          <div className={classes.links}>
            {/* <h2>Links</h2> */}

            <div className={classes.href}>
              <ul>
                <li className={classes.link_container}>
                  {" "}
                  <a href={`${weblink}`}>
                    <svg width={100} viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                      <path
                        fill="pink"
                        d="M3.51211712,15 L8.17190229,15 C8.05949197,14.0523506 8,13.0444554 8,12 C8,10.9555446 8.05949197,9.94764942 8.17190229,9 L3.51211712,9 C3.18046266,9.93833678 3,10.9480937 3,12 C3,13.0519063 3.18046266,14.0616632 3.51211712,15 L3.51211712,15 Z M3.93551965,16 C5.12590433,18.3953444 7.35207678,20.1851177 10.0280093,20.783292 C9.24889451,19.7227751 8.65216136,18.0371362 8.31375067,16 L3.93551965,16 L3.93551965,16 Z M20.4878829,15 C20.8195373,14.0616632 21,13.0519063 21,12 C21,10.9480937 20.8195373,9.93833678 20.4878829,9 L15.8280977,9 C15.940508,9.94764942 16,10.9555446 16,12 C16,13.0444554 15.940508,14.0523506 15.8280977,15 L20.4878829,15 L20.4878829,15 Z M20.0644804,16 L15.6862493,16 C15.3478386,18.0371362 14.7511055,19.7227751 13.9719907,20.783292 C16.6479232,20.1851177 18.8740957,18.3953444 20.0644804,16 L20.0644804,16 Z M9.18440269,15 L14.8155973,15 C14.9340177,14.0623882 15,13.0528256 15,12 C15,10.9471744 14.9340177,9.93761183 14.8155973,9 L9.18440269,9 C9.06598229,9.93761183 9,10.9471744 9,12 C9,13.0528256 9.06598229,14.0623882 9.18440269,15 L9.18440269,15 Z M9.3349823,16 C9.85717082,18.9678295 10.9180729,21 12,21 C13.0819271,21 14.1428292,18.9678295 14.6650177,16 L9.3349823,16 L9.3349823,16 Z M3.93551965,8 L8.31375067,8 C8.65216136,5.96286383 9.24889451,4.27722486 10.0280093,3.21670804 C7.35207678,3.81488234 5.12590433,5.60465556 3.93551965,8 L3.93551965,8 Z M20.0644804,8 C18.8740957,5.60465556 16.6479232,3.81488234 13.9719907,3.21670804 C14.7511055,4.27722486 15.3478386,5.96286383 15.6862493,8 L20.0644804,8 L20.0644804,8 Z M9.3349823,8 L14.6650177,8 C14.1428292,5.03217048 13.0819271,3 12,3 C10.9180729,3 9.85717082,5.03217048 9.3349823,8 L9.3349823,8 Z M12,22 C6.4771525,22 2,17.5228475 2,12 C2,6.4771525 6.4771525,2 12,2 C17.5228475,2 22,6.4771525 22,12 C22,17.5228475 17.5228475,22 12,22 Z"
                      />
                    </svg>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li className={classes.link_container}>
                  <a href={`${github}`}>
                    <svg width={100} viewBox="0 0 128 128">
                      <g fill="#181616">
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                          fill="pink"
                          d="M64 1.512c-23.493 0-42.545 19.047-42.545 42.545 0 18.797 12.19 34.745 29.095 40.37 2.126.394 2.907-.923 2.907-2.047 0-1.014-.04-4.366-.058-7.92-11.837 2.573-14.334-5.02-14.334-5.02-1.935-4.918-4.724-6.226-4.724-6.226-3.86-2.64.29-2.586.29-2.586 4.273.3 6.523 4.385 6.523 4.385 3.794 6.504 9.953 4.623 12.38 3.536.383-2.75 1.485-4.628 2.702-5.69-9.45-1.075-19.384-4.724-19.384-21.026 0-4.645 1.662-8.44 4.384-11.42-.442-1.072-1.898-5.4.412-11.26 0 0 3.572-1.142 11.7 4.363 3.395-.943 7.035-1.416 10.65-1.432 3.616.017 7.258.49 10.658 1.432 8.12-5.504 11.688-4.362 11.688-4.362 2.316 5.86.86 10.187.418 11.26 2.728 2.978 4.378 6.774 4.378 11.42 0 16.34-9.953 19.938-19.427 20.99 1.526 1.32 2.886 3.91 2.886 7.88 0 5.692-.048 10.273-.048 11.674 0 1.13.766 2.458 2.922 2.04 16.896-5.632 29.07-21.574 29.07-40.365C106.545 20.56 87.497 1.512 64 1.512z"
                        ></path>
                        <path d="M37.57 62.596c-.095.212-.428.275-.73.13-.31-.14-.482-.427-.382-.64.09-.216.424-.277.733-.132.31.14.486.43.38.642zM39.293 64.52c-.203.187-.6.1-.87-.198-.278-.297-.33-.694-.124-.884.208-.188.593-.1.87.197.28.3.335.693.123.884zm1.677 2.448c-.26.182-.687.012-.95-.367-.262-.377-.262-.83.005-1.013.264-.182.684-.018.95.357.262.385.262.84-.005 1.024zm2.298 2.368c-.233.257-.73.188-1.093-.163-.372-.343-.475-.83-.242-1.087.237-.257.736-.185 1.102.163.37.342.482.83.233 1.086zm3.172 1.374c-.104.334-.582.485-1.064.344-.482-.146-.796-.536-.7-.872.1-.336.582-.493 1.067-.342.48.144.795.53.696.87zm3.48.255c.013.35-.396.642-.902.648-.508.012-.92-.272-.926-.618 0-.354.4-.642.908-.65.506-.01.92.272.92.62zm3.24-.551c.06.342-.29.694-.793.787-.494.092-.95-.12-1.014-.46-.06-.35.297-.7.79-.792.503-.088.953.118 1.017.466zm0 0"></path>
                      </g>
                      <path
                        d="M24.855 108.302h-10.7a.5.5 0 00-.5.5v5.232a.5.5 0 00.5.5h4.173v6.5s-.937.32-3.53.32c-3.056 0-7.327-1.116-7.327-10.508 0-9.393 4.448-10.63 8.624-10.63 3.614 0 5.17.636 6.162.943.31.094.6-.216.6-.492l1.193-5.055a.468.468 0 00-.192-.39c-.403-.288-2.857-1.66-9.058-1.66-7.144 0-14.472 3.038-14.472 17.65 0 14.61 8.39 16.787 15.46 16.787 5.854 0 9.405-2.502 9.405-2.502.146-.08.162-.285.162-.38v-16.316a.5.5 0 00-.5-.5zM79.506 94.81H73.48a.5.5 0 00-.498.503l.002 11.644h-9.392V95.313a.5.5 0 00-.497-.503H57.07a.5.5 0 00-.498.503v31.53c0 .277.224.503.498.503h6.025a.5.5 0 00.497-.504v-13.486h9.392l-.016 13.486c0 .278.224.504.5.504h6.038a.5.5 0 00.497-.504v-31.53a.497.497 0 00-.497-.502zm-47.166.717c-2.144 0-3.884 1.753-3.884 3.923 0 2.167 1.74 3.925 3.884 3.925 2.146 0 3.885-1.758 3.885-3.925 0-2.17-1.74-3.923-3.885-3.923zm2.956 9.608H29.29c-.276 0-.522.284-.522.56v20.852c0 .613.382.795.876.795h5.41c.595 0 .74-.292.74-.805v-20.899a.5.5 0 00-.498-.502zm67.606.047h-5.98a.5.5 0 00-.496.504v15.46s-1.52 1.11-3.675 1.11-2.727-.977-2.727-3.088v-13.482a.5.5 0 00-.497-.504h-6.068a.502.502 0 00-.498.504v14.502c0 6.27 3.495 7.804 8.302 7.804 3.944 0 7.124-2.18 7.124-2.18s.15 1.15.22 1.285c.07.136.247.273.44.273l3.86-.017a.502.502 0 00.5-.504l-.003-21.166a.504.504 0 00-.5-.502zm16.342-.708c-3.396 0-5.706 1.515-5.706 1.515V95.312a.5.5 0 00-.497-.503H107a.5.5 0 00-.5.503v31.53a.5.5 0 00.5.503h4.192c.19 0 .332-.097.437-.268.103-.17.254-1.454.254-1.454s2.47 2.34 7.148 2.34c5.49 0 8.64-2.784 8.64-12.502s-5.03-10.988-8.428-10.988zm-2.36 17.764c-2.073-.063-3.48-1.004-3.48-1.004v-9.985s1.388-.85 3.09-1.004c2.153-.193 4.228.458 4.228 5.594 0 5.417-.935 6.486-3.837 6.398zm-63.689-.118c-.263 0-.937.107-1.63.107-2.22 0-2.973-1.032-2.973-2.368v-8.866h4.52a.5.5 0 00.5-.504v-4.856a.5.5 0 00-.5-.502h-4.52l-.007-5.97c0-.227-.116-.34-.378-.34h-6.16c-.238 0-.367.106-.367.335v6.17s-3.087.745-3.295.805a.5.5 0 00-.36.48v3.877a.5.5 0 00.497.503h3.158v9.328c0 6.93 4.86 7.61 8.14 7.61 1.497 0 3.29-.48 3.586-.59.18-.067.283-.252.283-.453l.004-4.265a.51.51 0 00-.5-.502z"
                        // fill="#100E0F"
                        fill="pink"
                      ></path>
                    </svg>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.tech}>
            <h2>Technologies Utilised</h2>
            <div className={classes.techList}>
              {tech.includes("CSS") && (
                <div className={classes.logo}>
                  {" "}
                  <Image
                    width={50}
                    height={50}
                    alt=" "
                    // src={require("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/css3/css3-original.svg")}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
              {tech.includes("HTML") && (
                <div className={classes.logo}>
                  <Image
                    width={50}
                    height={50}
                    alt=" "
                    // src={require("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/html5/html5-plain.svg")}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
              {tech.includes("JS") && (
                <div className={classes.logo}>
                  <Image
                    width={50}
                    height={50}
                    alt=" "
                    // src={require("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/javascript/javascript-plain.svg")}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
              {tech.includes("React") && (
                <div className={classes.logo}>
                  <Image
                    width={50}
                    height={50}
                    alt=" "
                    // src={require("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/devicons/devicon/icons/react/react-original.svg")}
                  />
                </div>
              )}
              {tech.includes("MySQL") && (
                <div className={classes.logo}>
                  <svg width="50" height="50" fill="grey" alt=" " viewBox="0 0 128 128">
                    <path d="M2.001 90.458h4.108V74.235l6.36 14.143c.75 1.712 1.777 2.317 3.792 2.317s3.003-.605 3.753-2.317l6.36-14.143v16.223h4.108V74.262c0-1.58-.632-2.345-1.936-2.739-3.121-.974-5.215-.131-6.163 1.976l-6.241 13.958-6.043-13.959c-.909-2.106-3.042-2.949-6.163-1.976C2.632 71.917 2 72.681 2 74.261v16.197zm31.898-13.206h4.107v8.938c-.038.485.156 1.625 2.406 1.661 1.148.018 8.862 0 8.934 0V77.208h4.117c.019 0-.004 14.514-.004 14.574.022 3.58-4.441 4.357-6.499 4.417H33.988v-2.764c.022 0 12.963.003 12.995-.001 2.645-.279 2.332-1.593 2.331-2.035v-1.078h-8.731c-4.062-.037-6.65-1.81-6.683-3.85-.002-.187.089-9.129-.001-9.219zM56.63 90.458h11.812c1.383 0 2.727-.289 3.793-.789 1.777-.816 2.646-1.922 2.646-3.372v-3.002c0-1.185-.987-2.292-2.923-3.028-1.027-.396-2.292-.605-3.517-.605h-4.978c-1.659 0-2.449-.5-2.646-1.606-.039-.132-.039-.237-.039-.369v-1.87c0-.105 0-.211.039-.342.197-.843.632-1.08 2.094-1.212l.395-.026h11.733v-2.738H63.504c-1.659 0-2.528.105-3.318.342-2.449.764-3.517 1.975-3.517 4.082v2.396c0 1.844 2.095 3.424 5.61 3.793.396.025.79.053 1.185.053h4.267c.158 0 .316 0 .435.025 1.304.105 1.856.343 2.252.816a.98.98 0 01.315.737v2.397c0 .289-.197.658-.592.974-.355.316-.948.527-1.738.58l-.435.026H56.63v2.738zm43.881-4.766c0 2.817 2.094 4.397 6.32 4.714.395.026.79.052 1.185.052h10.706V87.72h-10.784c-2.41 0-3.318-.606-3.318-2.055V71.497h-4.108v14.195zm-23.008.142v-9.765c0-2.48 1.742-3.985 5.186-4.46a7.8 7.8 0 011.108-.079h7.799c.396 0 .752.026 1.147.079 3.444.475 5.187 1.979 5.187 4.46v9.765c0 2.014-.74 3.09-2.445 3.792l4.048 3.653h-4.771l-3.274-2.956-3.296.209h-4.395a9.075 9.075 0 01-2.414-.343c-2.613-.712-3.88-2.085-3.88-4.355zm4.435-.237c0 .132.039.265.079.423.237 1.135 1.307 1.768 2.929 1.768h3.732l-3.428-3.095h4.771l2.989 2.7c.552-.295.914-.743 1.041-1.32.039-.132.039-.264.039-.396v-9.368c0-.105 0-.238-.039-.37-.238-1.056-1.307-1.662-2.89-1.662h-6.216c-1.82 0-3.008.792-3.008 2.032v9.288zm40.398-18.645c-2.525-.069-4.454.166-6.104.861-.469.198-1.216.203-1.292.79.257.271.297.674.502 1.006.394.637 1.059 1.491 1.652 1.938.647.489 1.315 1.013 2.011 1.437 1.235.754 2.615 1.184 3.806 1.938.701.446 1.397 1.006 2.082 1.509.339.247.565.634 1.006.789v-.071c-.231-.294-.291-.698-.503-1.006l-.934-.934c-.913-1.212-2.071-2.275-3.304-3.159-.982-.705-3.18-1.658-3.59-2.801l-.072-.071c.696-.079 1.512-.331 2.154-.503 1.08-.29 2.045-.215 3.16-.503l1.508-.432v-.286c-.563-.578-.966-1.344-1.58-1.867-1.607-1.369-3.363-2.737-5.17-3.879-1.002-.632-2.241-1.043-3.304-1.579-.356-.181-.984-.274-1.221-.575-.559-.711-.862-1.612-1.293-2.441a93.068 93.068 0 01-2.585-5.458c-.544-1.245-.9-2.473-1.579-3.59-3.261-5.361-6.771-8.597-12.208-11.777-1.157-.677-2.55-.943-4.021-1.292l-2.37-.144c-.481-.201-.983-.791-1.436-1.077-1.802-1.138-6.422-3.613-7.756-.358-.842 2.054 1.26 4.058 2.011 5.099.527.73 1.203 1.548 1.58 2.369.248.54.29 1.081.503 1.652.521 1.406.976 2.937 1.651 4.236.341.658.718 1.351 1.149 1.939.264.36.718.52.789 1.077-.443.62-.469 1.584-.718 2.369-1.122 3.539-.699 7.938.934 10.557.501.805 1.681 2.529 3.303 1.867 1.419-.578 1.103-2.369 1.509-3.95.092-.357.035-.621.215-.861v.072l1.293 2.585c.957 1.541 2.654 3.15 4.093 4.237.746.563 1.334 1.538 2.298 1.867v-.073h-.071c-.188-.291-.479-.411-.719-.646-.562-.551-1.187-1.235-1.651-1.867-1.309-1.776-2.465-3.721-3.519-5.745-.503-.966-.94-2.032-1.364-3.016-.164-.379-.162-.953-.502-1.148-.466.72-1.149 1.303-1.509 2.154-.574 1.36-.648 3.019-.861 4.739l-.144.071c-1.001-.241-1.352-1.271-1.724-2.154-.94-2.233-1.115-5.83-.287-8.401.214-.666 1.181-2.761.789-3.376-.187-.613-.804-.967-1.148-1.437a11.222 11.222 0 01-1.149-2.011c-.77-1.741-1.129-3.696-1.938-5.457-.388-.842-1.042-1.693-1.58-2.441-.595-.83-1.262-1.44-1.724-2.442-.164-.356-.387-.927-.144-1.293.077-.247.188-.35.432-.431.416-.321 1.576.107 2.01.287 1.152.479 2.113.934 3.089 1.58.468.311.941.911 1.508 1.077h.646c1.011.232 2.144.071 3.088.358 1.67.508 3.166 1.297 4.524 2.155 4.139 2.614 7.522 6.334 9.838 10.772.372.715.534 1.396.861 2.154.662 1.528 1.496 3.101 2.154 4.596.657 1.491 1.298 2.996 2.227 4.237.488.652 2.374 1.002 3.231 1.364.601.254 1.585.519 2.154.861 1.087.656 2.141 1.437 3.16 2.155.509.362 2.076 1.149 2.154 1.798zM90.237 39.593a5.124 5.124 0 00-1.293.144v.071h.072c.251.517.694.849 1.005 1.293l.719 1.508.071-.071c.445-.313.648-.814.646-1.58-.179-.188-.205-.423-.359-.646-.204-.3-.602-.468-.861-.719z"></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              )}
              {/* <p>{tech.map((t) => `${t} `)}</p> */}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.block}></div>
        </div>

        <div
          className={
            (`bg-white`, router.query.projectId != "Bike Website" ? classes.development_alt : classes.development)
          }
        >
          <div className={router.query.projectId != "Bike Website" ? classes.dev_image_alt : classes.dev_image}>
            <Image
              src={image}
              alt=" "
              // width={700}
              // height={400}
              // width={router.query.projectId != "Bicycle Website" ? 800 : 400}
              // height={router.query.projectId != "Bicycle Website" ? 400 : 200}
            ></Image>
            {router.query.projectId != "Bike Website" && (
              <Image
                src={imageTwo}
                alt=" "
                // width={800}
                // height={400}
                // width={router.query.projectId != "Bicycle Website" ? 800 : 400}
                // height={router.query.projectId != "Bicycle Website" ? 400 : 200}
              ></Image>
            )}
          </div>
          <div className={classes.objective}>
            <h3>Objective</h3>
            <p>{objective}</p>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.mainText}>
            <h3>Inspiration</h3>
            <p>{development}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.footer}>
          <p>this is a footer</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      )
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you load the main page and click the project links, everything is fine, but if you use a direct link to a project, then you get the error?

From looking at your code, I would guess that you populate `projectData` on the main page and that it is `null|undefined|empty` if you visit a project site directly.

You need to ensure that the `projectData` is available when you are doing the lookup -- maybe try loading the project async?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try and figure out how to do that. I actually just added the following code -   if (!currentProject) return <p></p>; and it seems to work now. I'm not sure if thus the best method but it seems to be working for the moment.